# Wifi gone after latest Ubuntu 14.04 update on August 25, 2016

Tags: 14.04, networking, broadcom

[Broadcom driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IWnm.png)

After an upgrade to my 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS today, my wireless card is no longer noticed. It is a Broadcom, using their driver.

> 09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
>
> 0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

Ethernet still works.

Going back to a previous Ubuntu temporarily solves the problem.

My computer is an old (2008) Dell XPS laptop. I've never had any wireless problems until today.

Following the directions shown did not fix the problem:

> WARNING: Security updates for your current Hardware Enablement
>   Stack ended on 2016-08-04:
>   * http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL
>
> There is a graphics stack installed on this system. An upgrade to a
>   configuration supported for the full lifetime of the LTS will become
>   available on 2016-07-21 and can be installed by running 'update-manager'
>   in the Dash.

Any thoughts? Thanks, Bill

Comment: Thank you - you are correct. Switching to firmware-b43-installer solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have proprietary drivers enabled?

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/drivers

Comment: I believe the proprietary driver `bcmwl-kernel-source` is incorrect for his device.

Comment: Yes, I used the Broadcom driver. I edited my initial post to include a link to a picture of this. 

It is indeed bcmwl-kernel-source, but it has always worked until the Ubuntu software update.